# Do music stars rehearse regularly with their band?

Tags: rehearsal

I was wondering , do music stars like David Gilmour , Phil Collins (etc.) 
rehearse each rehearsal with their band ( not the original band , but their band - for example : David Gilmour doesn't perform with the Pink Floyd but his own band).

**Question**

Do they rehearse themselves each rehearsal with their band - or there is some kind of "my music/studio manager" which actually do the rehearsals and then  David joins in to the last couple of rehearsals ?

Comment: It is hard work playing in successful band. These things do not come easily.

Comment: @NeilMeyer Yes that's for sure. I was just wondering about a situation whhere David gilmour might think : "Oh boy ,  now I got to teach them exactly how to play pinkfloyd's songs as I want them to be in a show - I don't have time for this shi* "

Comment: Regardless of how they rehearse, you can be sure that almost all professionals at the level of David Gilmour or Phil Collins rehearse quite a bit.

Comment: @RockinCowboy - There are exceptions to every rule.  I'm thinking of Rostropovich.

Comment: @aparente001 - yes there are a few musical geniuses that have emerged throughout history.

Comment: @RockinCowboy - But we mere mortals do need to practice and rehearse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple: **Everybody does this his own way.**

David Gilmour is known to rehearse *a lot* with his bands. He's someone who values the chemistry between band members very highly, and he also gets a lot of important input from the people around him. Jon Carin, Guy Pratt and Dick Parry are a few people who are known to have contributed very much to the music of David Gilmour and Pink Floyd.

The Beatles are an example of a band that hardly did any rehearsals in their later days. They composed some songs, then got together, practiced a little, then started recording almost immediately. Some songs had hardly been practiced as a band at all, and some songs (especially the more experimental ones like *Wild Honey Pie*) went from being composed straight to being recorded in the studio, without any practice whatsoever.

Comment: Regarding the Beatles , I find it hard to believe. The white album is one of their latest albums , and it has many complex songs which they MUST rehearse a lot I assume. - not to mention that it is  a single long track album( most of it). I think you're talking about the period before SGT pepper where john wrote some songs and then paul ( john jsut did how i won the war) and then they got together to record songs. but in their last albums - their sure did a lot of rehursals.

Comment: In fact, the opposite is true. :-) They were great musicians, but could barely stand being together in a studio. During their early days they played together a lot, but their last albums were hardly rehearsed for at all. The White Album wasn't extreme yet in that regard, but Let It Be and Abbey Road had hardly any rehearsals at all.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this has a definite answer. There are music stars that would rehearse with the band at all rehearsals and there are others that would join them in the last 2-3 rehearsals.

This would depend on a few reasons; If the band doesn't know the songs, the 'music star' might be bored to be there when they learn them, so he/she might wait for them to learn the songs and then join them. But also, it might be possible that he/she wants to oversee what is going on in the rehearsals, so he might be there from the beginning.

This would differ from artist to artist. The thing you can do is to look up and see if you can find anything on the artist you are interested in.

<sub>If a star is much of a diva, I doubt he/she will rehearse regularly</sub>